# coldfusion 9 orm - how to define relationship

Tags: database, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

now pretend you have a db structure like this:

table *Object*

```
{
    id,
    name
}
```

table *ObjectRelation*

```
{
    id,
    parentID, -- points to id in the object table
    childID   -- points to id in the object table
}
```

what i'd like to have in my model is the following:

```
{
    property name
    property children
    property parent
}
```

how would you guys define the parent property in this case? keep in mind that the root element(s) obviously don't have a parent object.

Comment: I think you just want one-to-many for both children and parent

Comment: i don't think so, that way i get an inner join and the objects without parent won't be listed/fetched

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
component persistent="true" {
property name="id" ormtype="integer" type="numeric" column="id" fieldtype="id" generator="identity";
property name="name";
property name="children"
    fieldtype="one-to-many"
    cfc="Object"
    linktable="ObjectRelation"
    fkcolumn="parentID"
    singularname="child"
    lazy=true
    inversejoincolumn="childID";
property name="parent"
    fieldtype="many-to-one"
    cfc="Object"
    linktable="ObjectRelation"
    fkcolumn="childID"
    lazy=true
    inversejoincolumn="parentID";
}
```